# How to Parse Nested Dictionary JSON Data in iOS?

Tags: ios, json, dictionary, uicollectionview

i am newbie in iOS Development. i want to parse my this JSON Data into to array First array Contain all Data and Second array Contain only  -demopage: array Value.

```
status: "success",
-data: [
 {
   mid: "5",
   name: "October 2014",
   front_image: "http://www.truemanindiamagazine.com/webservice/magazineimage/frontimage/01.jpg",
   title: "October 2014",
   release_date: "2014-10-01",
   short_description: "As the name suggest itself “Trueman India” will cover icons of India. Our national Magazine “Trueman India” is an expansion to our business, i",
   current_issue: 0,
 -demopage: [
   {
   link: "http://www.truemanindiamagazine.com/webservice/magazineimage/pageimage/2014/10/01-1413806104.jpg",
   page_no: "1"
   },
   {
   link: "http://www.truemanindiamagazine.com/webservice/magazineimage/pageimage/2014/10/2-1413806131.jpg",
   page_no: "2"
   },
   {
  link: "http://www.truemanindiamagazine.com/webservice/magazineimage/pageimage/2014/10/3-1413806170.jpg",
   page_no: "3"
   }
   ]
  }
  ]
```

Here my main Dictionary Key is data i want data keey value in my One array and demopage key value in to another array here my two Array is self.imageArray and self.imagesa here my code For that

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustumCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
    data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: imgURL];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
});
}
-(void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responsedata
{
NSMutableArray *imagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
if (responsedata.length > 0)
{
    NSError* error;

    self.json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responsedata options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    if ([[_json objectForKey:@"data"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
        NSArray *arr = (NSArray *)[_json objectForKey:@"data"];
        [self.imageArray addObjectsFromArray:arr];
        [self.storeTable reloadData];
    }
    self.storeTable.hidden=FALSE;
    for (index=0; index<[self.imageArray count]; index++)
    {
        for(NSDictionary *dict in self.imageArray)
        {
            imagesArray = [dict valueForKey:@"demopage"];
            self.imagesa = imagesArray;
        }
        NSLog(@"New Demo page array %@",self.imagesa);
    }

}
```

then i get my data key value and it is ok but i got only last index means here my -data key Contain three -demopage key and i get only last -demopage key value i want all -demopage key value in to self.imagesa please give me solution for that.
also my Webservices link is  [Link](http://www.truemanindiamagazine.com/webservice/magazine_list.php)

Comment: can u add your full WebServices Data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get -data in **NSMutableArray**.

```
NSMutableArray *dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *imagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responsedata options:kNilOptions error:&error];
dataArray=[json objectForKey:@"data"];

for(NSDictionary *dict in dataArray )
{
  imagesArray = [dict valueForKey:@"demopage"];
  self.imagesa = imagesArray;
 }

[selt.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: #Fawad i got the data as i want but how i display in collection view cell? i write a code for Collectionview Cell
 CustumCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSDictionary *dict = [self.imagesa objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    NSString *img2=[dict valueForKey:@"link"];
    [cell.imageview sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:img2] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];
    return cell; but it not working

Comment: Check if the method cellForItemAtIndexPath is called. If it called NSLog the img2 string and tell me if it is displaying or not. Also check if you have set the delegate of cell like cell.delegate = self.

Comment: Bro the method is not called which problem i not know i am so tired please give me solution.

Comment: have you set the delegate of your collectionView? check please. Also in numberOfItemsInSection method, enter self.imagesa.count.

Comment: i write a code for cellForItemAtIndexPath is Right or not? if it was Right then i try it with second project

Comment: If your delegate methods are set and self.imagesa.count>0, it is not possible that the method is not called. Have created collectionView programmatically?

Comment: No i not Created Collectionview programmatically and also i remove that code from method numberOfItemsInSection and replace it with return self.imagesa.count

Comment: yes your code for cellForItemAtIndexPath is correct. Just add cell.delegate = self.

Answer (score 2):

You can give it a try like this:

```
NSError* error;
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responsedata options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSDictionary *dataDict = [json objectForKey:@"data"];
NSArray *imageArray = [dataDict objectForKey:@"demopage"];
self.imagesa = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
    NSString *imageUrl = [dict objectForKey:@"link"];
    [self.imagesa addObject:imageUrl];
}
```

Then you got imageArray as dataSource for the `collectionView`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `SBJson` library, but not the last 4th version:

```
pod 'SBJson', '3.2'
```

Sample code, I changed variable names and formatting a little bit:

```
// Create a JSON String from NSData
NSData *responseData = [NSData new]; // Here you should use your responseData
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

if (! jsonString ) {
   // Handle errors
}

// Create SBJsonParser instance
SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

// Parse JSON String to dictionary
NSDictionary *jsonDic = [jsonParser objectWithString:jsonString];

// Get an array by key
NSArray *dicArray = [jsonDic objectForKey:@"demopage"];

// Reload collection view
if ( [dicArray count] > 0 ) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Reload Your Collection View Here and use dicArray (in your case imagesa array with dictionaries)
    });
}
```

And when you set a cell, you can use something like this:

```
NSDictionary *dic = dicArray[indexPath.row];
NSString *link = dic[@"link"];
NSString *pageNo = dic[@"page_no"];
```